# LED replacement for cicline CFL lamp

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, cfl

I have a ceiling fan with an FCL-30EX circline bulb. It's marked as 2700K, 30W, 120V. My main issue is that it is very dim. I would like to replace it with an equivalent of 100W if possible.
Led would be preferable. Does such a replacement exist? 
Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to convert to a led but without rewiring the ballast I did not see a direct led replacement look for a circle lamp retrofit kit. I did see both 8" & 12" models but not one for your lamp type.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search using The Google with the terms "FCL-30EX circline bulb led replacement" results in many links, although The Google prefers to search without the hyphen, "FCL30EX circline bulb led replacement." Additional research shows the CFL tube you reference is a nine inch diameter unit. Many LED replacements for this tube are plug-in without complications. Keep in mind that rating a CFL bulb for 30W is not the equivalent of an incandescent bulb at 30W. This would indicate that your desired 100W equivalent, if available would be blindingly bright.

A representative sample from amazon.com is listed at 30W, 1700 lumens:
[CFL Replacement LED circline bulb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N5RBIMI) although the comments indicate that it may be necessary to remove the ballast.

Use your favorite search engine with the previously noted terms for more options.

Answer (score 0):

There are LED replacements for screw-in incandescent bulbs and so for compact fluorescent tubes which are themselves direct replacements for incandescent bulbs. These work directly from 120 V 60 hz ac.

But AFIK there are no LED direct replacements for plug-in fluorescent tubes.

The reason is that fluorescent tubes are powered from a "ballast", which is an electronic device which changes regular ac 120 V 60 hz to a different type of power which the tubes require. The compact fluorescent tubes have a mini-ballast built into the tube.

There are conversion kits to allow fixtures for 4 ft fluorescent tubes to power long LED arrays, but it is not a simple plug in. The ballast has to be disconnected and a special power supply for the LEDs added in the fixture. I have not seen such kits for circline fluorescent tubes. But if they exist, you might locate them by Googling LED replacement for circular fluorescent tubes. I assume that a circline fluorescent has a separate ballast in the housing. Google replacing ballast for circular fluorescent tube fixture.

**EDIT**

Looks like there are LED replacements for circular fluorescent tubes [http://www.homedepot.com/p/Aspects-22W-Equivalent-Warm-White-T9-Dimmable-LED-Retrofit-Kit-RFKIT22/207056636?MERCH=REC-_-piphorizontal2_rr-1-*-207056638-*-207056636-_-N](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Aspects-22W-Equivalent-Warm-White-T9-Dimmable-LED-Retrofit-Kit-RFKIT22/207056636?MERCH=REC-_-piphorizontal2_rr-1-_-207056638-_-207056636-_-N)